# How to separate ring from cluster in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

We have a cassandra DSE cluster with 10 nodes for cassandra ring and 10 nodes for hadoop ring. Now the application writes the data to the cassandra ring and cassandra will replicate the data to hadoop ring.

We want to separate the two ring's and make them as two different cluster's and application writes the data to two clusters at the same time.

How to separate the cluster? is that possible?
we have ~600GB of data in the cluster and we cannot delete it.

Answer (score 4):

You should test this first, but this basic procedure should work. It will need some tweaking if you have counters.

1. Set your application writing to both DCs using LOCAL_QUORUM.
2. Run repair on the whole cluster. This is to ensure each DC has a copy of the data.
3. Isolate the clusters so the two DCs can't talk to each other, probably using a firewall.
4. Assuming your DCs are DC1 and DC2, change your replication factor to be DC2:0 on DC1 and DC1:0 on DC2.
5. On each DC, run 'nodetool removenode' for each node in the other DC. This will just remove the DOWN nodes from the ring but won't have any affect on the data because the other nodes have replication factor zero.

This should work with zero data loss.